# Galaxy S4 and Motorola CS3070, got paired but NOT connected

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, bluetooth-pairing

I am trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy S4 to a Bluetooth scanner Motorola CS3070 *unsuccessfully*.

Anybody aware of any compatibility issues or fixes?

Answer (score 2):

According to the GS4's [specifications](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/smart-phones/GT-I9500ZKAMID-spec), it supports the following Bluetooth profiles only:

- PBAP - Phone Book Access Profile
- A2DP - Advanced Audio Distribution Profile
- AVRCP - Audio/Video Remote Control Profile
- HFP - Hands-Free Profile
- HSP - Headset Profile
- OPP - Object Push Profile
- SAP - SIM Access Profile
- HID - Human Interface Device Profile
- PAN - Personal Area Networking Profile
- MAP - Message Access Profile

Your Motorola CS3070 scanner [supports](http://www.barcodesinc.com/pdf/Motorola/cs3000.pdf) the following BT profiles:

- HID - keyboard wedge
- **SPP - Serial Port Profile**

I believe the absence of SPP profile support on GS4 could be the reason you cannot properly connect the two devices without additional software.

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE3pE6ieNnI), software called "[BluePiano](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tecit.android.bluepiano.full)" can be used with this scanner model.  In the comments they specifically mention the SPP profile, and that there should be instructions in the scanner's manual on getting it to work with some handsets.